# Map retornando valores repetidos

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap

Estou fazendo um `foreach` num `hashmap` com base no seguinte `arquivo.txt`:

```
chaveA;6
chaveA;4
chaveB;3
chaveB;7
chaveC;1
chaveC;1
chaveD;5
```

Por enquanto meu código está assim:

```
Scanner scanArquivo = new Scanner(new File("arquivo.txt"));
HashMap<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<String, String>();
String linha[];

    while (scanArquivo.hasNext()) {

        linha = scanArquivo.nextLine().split(";");
        mapa.put(linha[0], linha[1]);
        mapa.forEach((chave, valor) -> {
            if (chave.equals("prdA")) System.out.println("Primeira chave");
        });
    }   
    scanArquivo.close();
```

Para cada linha, faço um split do arquivo para separar as informações e joga-las no Map. Tendo isso em mente, surge dois problemas.

Primeiro: O map me retorna informações duplicadas. A saída desse código me exibe mais linhas do que tem no próprio arquivo.

```
Primeira chave
Primeira chave
Primeira chave
Primeira chave
Primeira chave
Primeira chave
Primeira chave
```

Segundo: Aqui é mais um problema de algoritmo. Para cada chave diferente quero o valor mais alto. Como posso implementar isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes, o primeiro ponto a destacar é relacionado ao funcionamento do `HashMap`, é importante dizer que ele **não aceita chaves duplicadas**.

A apresentação de chaves iguais é devido ao modo como você está imprimindo o mapa:

```
while (scanArquivo.hasNext()) {

    linha = scanArquivo.nextLine().split(";"); // *** Aqui você lê uma linha ***
    mapa.put(linha[0], linha[1]);
    mapa.forEach((chave, valor) -> { 

        // *** Para cada linha que você lê, você percorre todos os elementos do mapa
        // Desta forma, se você percorrer todos os elementos, o primeiro elemento sempre vai existir :)

        if (chave.equals("prdA")) System.out.println("Primeira chave");
    });
}
```

---

Caso ocorra de você incluir no mapa uma chave que já exista, o método irá lhe retornar o objeto anterior relacionado à chave, por exemplo:

```
 // Aqui estou simulando a leitura de seu arquivo 
 // por completo, antes de apresentar os valores

    Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<>();

    mapa.put("chaveA", "6");
    mapa.put("chaveA", "4"); // Ao colocar a chaveA novamente, será retornado o valor 6
    mapa.put("chaveB", "3");
    mapa.put("chaveB", "7"); // Ao colocar a chaveB novamente, será retornado o valor 3
    mapa.put("chaveC", "1");
    mapa.put("chaveC", "1"); // Ao colocar a chaveC novamente, será retornado o valor 1
    mapa.put("chaveD", "5");
```

Desta forma, como você procura o valor mais alto de cada chave, você terá de fazer um tratamento ao montar seu `Map` parecido com este:

```
    Integer valorAnterior = mapa.put(chave, valor); // Inclui o novo valor e recupera o anterior relacionado à chave do mapa

    if( valorAnterior != null ) {
        if( valorAnterior > valor ) { // Caso exista, verifica se o anterior era maior que o atual
            mapa.put(chave, valorAnterior); // Mantêm o valor anterior se for maior que o atual
        }
    }
```

---

Após você ler o arquivo, incluir todos os registros no mapa, agora sim podemos exibir todas as chaves usando seu `forEach`, o resultado será este:

```
chaveB 7
chaveA 6
chaveD 5
chaveC 1
```

Espero ter ajudado!

---

**UPDATE**: Você pode conferir a [documentação do HashMap aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-)

Comment: Ajudou muito irmão! Vlw mesmo!!